# Batch Forecasting; using apply() function instead of for loop. apply() function gives different point forecast

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, forecasting

So far I was using [this](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/batch-forecasting/) method from professor Hyndman when I had multiple time series to forecast. But when I have a large number of ts it is fairly slow.

Now I am trying to use `apply()` function as follows

```
library(forecast)

fc_func <- function(y){
  forecast(auto.arima(y),h=12)$mean
}

retail <- read.csv("https://robjhyndman.com/data/ausretail.csv",header=FALSE)
retail <- ts(retail[,-1],f=12,s=1982+3/12)

  frc<- apply(retail,2 ,fc_func)
```

It seem that it is working well but when I use `for` loop as following:

```
ns <- ncol(retail)
h <- 12
fcast <- matrix(NA,nrow=h,ncol=ns)
for(i in 1:ns){
  fcast[,i] <- forecast(auto.arima(retail[,i]),h=h)$mean
}
```

I get different point forecast. What is the reason?

**Edit:** I fixed it by changing the "fc_func" function. Now it returns the same results as `for` loop but now it is also as slow as `for` loop

```
fc_func <- function(x){

ts(x,f=12,s=1982+3/12)->y

 forecast(auto.arima(y),h=12)$mean
}

retail <- read.csv("https://robjhyndman.com/data/ausretail.csv",header=FALSE)
retail <- ts(retail[,-1],f=12,s=1982+3/12)

  frc<- apply(retail,2 ,fc_func)
```

Comment: I think this shouldn't be the case :D I would try to first check if the input-data are the same in both versions. Maybe by printing y in the apply and retail[,i] in the for loop and compare them. Then i would compare the direct output in both versions for each variable, once again by printing them. If there are no differences both in input and output it has to be something with the way the data gets stored in the final object.

Comment: The code is re-applicable, I guess anyone would see that those two methods are returning different point forecast although they use same forecasting function.

Comment: It is, one has just to add a little 1 to make it running :) However, this is strange, im going to add my thoughts as an answer, so i can show code a bit more appealing

Comment: I see that :). it is corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `apply()` manipulating the class of the `time series` object, *retail*. Being the rudimentary version of the *apply* family, `apply()` is best used for simple matrix objects. It will cast its input to a matrix object with `as.matrix()` when called and hence why `apply()` is often warned not to be used for data frames.

Per the `?apply` docs:

> If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim
>   value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array
>   via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via
>   as.array

So `apply` does not preserve the class object of its input before being processed into `fc_func`:

```
class(retail)
# [1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"
```

One can see this when using `sapply` which runs just as slow as `for` and in removing `dimnames` returns exactly as `for` loop:

```
# LOOP VERSION
ns <- ncol(retail)
h <- 12
fcast1 <- matrix(NA,nrow=h,ncol=ns)

for(i in 1:ns) {
  fcast1[,i] <- forecast(auto.arima(retail[,i]), h=h)$mean
}

# SAPPLY VERSION
frc_test <- sapply(retail, fc_func, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
dimnames(frc_test) <- NULL

identical(frc_test, fcast1)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Is there no way to improve this issue?

Comment: Forgive me but that was not your question. I believe you asked for the reason: *I get different point forecast. What is the reason?* Definitely don't use `apply` for this call.

Comment: As for performance, look into parallel processing. I see `?auto.arima` has a *num.cores* argument.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will rearrange this question and maybe post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging i've added some prints in the apply. The interesting one is the class(y)

```
library(forecast)

fc_func <- function(y){
  print(length(y))
  print(class(y))
  #print(y)
  forecast(auto.arima(y),h=12)$mean
}

retail <- read.csv("https://robjhyndman.com/data/ausretail.csv",header=FALSE)
retail <- ts(retail[,-1],f=12,s=1982+3/12)

retail2 = retail

#retail = retail2[1:333,1:42]

frc<- apply(retail,2 ,fc_func)
```

All the y arrive as numeric at apply.

```
> frc<- apply(retail,2 ,fc_func)
[1] 333
[1] "numeric"
[1] 333
[1] "numeric"
[1] 333
[1] "numeric"
[1] 333
[1] "numeric"
[1] 333
```

This is different in the for-loop:

```
ns <- ncol(retail)
h <- 12
fcast1 <- matrix(NA,nrow=h,ncol=ns)
for(i in 1:ns){
  print(length(retail[,i]))
  print(class(retail[,i]))
  #print(retail[,i])
  fcast1[,i] <- forecast(auto.arima(retail[,i]),h=h)$mean
}
```

here the variables are delivered as ts to auto.arima.

```
> for(i in 1:ns){
+   print(length(retail[,i]))
+   print(class(retail[,i]))
+   #print(retail[,i])
+   fcast1[,i] <- forecast(auto.arima(retail[,i]),h=h)$mean
+ }
[1] 333
[1] "ts"
[1] 333
[1] "ts"
[1] 333
[1] "ts"
[1] 333
```

I guess this causes the differences, because when i reduce retail to a simple matrix by

```
retail = retail[1:NROW(retail), 1:NCOL(retail)]
```

and run the for-loop again i get perfectly the same results as in the apply version.

```
all.equal(frc, fcast1)
```

So i guess you have to transform the variables to ts within the the fc_func again before sending them into the forecast function.

As a workaround (and because i had no idea how to transform y into the desired ts object) you could use an sapply version:

```
fc_func2 <- function(y){

  forecast(auto.arima(retail[,y]),h=12)$mean
}

frc2 <- sapply(1:NCOL(retail), fc_func2)
```

It should give the desired values, but im not sure if it is any faster than the loop-version.